# Properly send value through many intents

Tags: java, android

I have tried all the good ole fashion ways of sending data through intents such as getExtra and putExtra. However, this certain piece of information will not travel through intents. The variable is initialized here (driverId):

```
   private void findDriver() {
        DatabaseReference drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.driver_tbl);
        GeoFire gfDrivers = new GeoFire(drivers);
        GeoQuery geoQuery = gfDrivers.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()),radius);
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                if(!Common.isDriverFound){
                    Common.isDriverFound = true;
                    Common.driverId = key;
                    btnPickupRequest.setText("CALL SUB");
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this,""+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

I then send the information for driverId when a button is clicked here:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, CallDriver.class);

 intent.putExtra("driverId",marker.getSnippet());
 intent.putExtra("lat",mLastLocation.getLatitude());
 intent.putExtra("lng",mLastLocation.getLongitude());
 startActivity(intent);
```

I then call the information in the text intent like so:

```
 if (driverId != null && !driverId.isEmpty())
                if (getIntent() !=null) {
                    driverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("driverId");
                }
                sendRequestToDriver(driverId, mService, getBaseContext(), mLastLocation);
        }
```

My send request to driver method is:

```
 public static void sendRequestToDriver(String driverId,final IFCMService mService,final Context context,final Location currentLocation) {

        DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.token_tbl);

        tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(driverId)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            Token token = postSnapShot.getValue(Token.class);

                            //String json_lat_lng = new Gson().toJson(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                            String riderToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();



                            Map<String,String> content = new HashMap<>();
                            content.put("customer", riderToken);
                            content.put("driverId",driverId);
                            content.put("lat",String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLatitude()));
                            content.put("lng",String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLongitude()));
                            DataMessage dataMessage = new DataMessage(token.getToken(),content);
                            Log.d(String.valueOf(dataMessage), "here big boy"+dataMessage);

                            mService.sendMessage(dataMessage).enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponse> call, Response<FCMResponse> response) {
                                    if(response.body().success == 1)
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Request Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    else
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<FCMResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                    Log.e("Error", t.getMessage());
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

    }
```

Now when I try to receive the information on the intent RateActivity, I get a null value. How can I make sure that the string driverId is properly initialized or the data stays throughout these intents?

Comment: Try saving this id in a sharedPreferences, just remember to remove if you don't need it anymore

Comment: well your intent is sent to ```CallDriver.class``` so i am not sure which your RateActivity is. If both are the same check if ```marker.getSnippet()``` actually has any String value to send in "driverId"

Answer (score 0):

try this `intent.putExtra("driverId",marker.getSnippet().toString());
       intent.putExtra("lat",mLastLocation.getLatitude().toString());
       intent.putExtra("lng",mLastLocation.getLongitude().toString());`